# ASP.NET Site Error on Different Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a a project that have been deployed on a server. Everything is okay ( I can access it using multiple browser) But different case with IE 11.

What make it weird is, I can access my localhost using IE 11 which build on the same project, but once I deploy it, my IE 11 doesnt allow me to login and redirect me to error page, also the link are broken (other browser include IE 9 are fine).

I use IE 11.0.9, Windows 7, and .Net Framework 4 on my Lcoal and 
on my server I use Windows Server R2 Data Center and .Net framework 4 too.

What I did so far is:

1. Copy paste my ie.browser file on .Net config directory (local) to server, (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config)
2. run aspnet_regbrowsers -i
3. Restart IIS.

Here's my ie.browser that exist on my pc (local)

```
<browsers>
    <browser id="IE" parentID="Mozilla">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="MSIE (?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
            <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
        </identification>

        <capture>
            <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
        </capture>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
            <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
            <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
            <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
            <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
            <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
            <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
            <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
            <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
            <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
            <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>

    <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4325) -->
    <browser id="IE6to9" parentID="IE">
        <identification>
            <capability name="majorversion" match="[6-9]" />
        </identification>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
            <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
            <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
            <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
            <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
            <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
            <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
            <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
            <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
            <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
            <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
            <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
            <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
            <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
            <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>

    <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;) -->
    <browser id="IE7" parentID="IE6to9">
        <identification>
            <capability name="majorversion" match="7" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="jscriptversion" value="5.7" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>

    <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729) -->
    <browser id="IE8" parentID="IE6to9">
        <identification>
            <capability name="majorversion" match="8" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>

    <gateway id="IEbeta" parentID="IE">
        <identification>
            <capability name="letters" match="^([bB]|ab)" />
        </identification>

        <capture>
        </capture>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="beta"    value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>
</browsers>
```

Still not working though. 
Does anyone have a better approach to this case.

Update: I found error in:
**WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is undefined**

Comment: Can you install .NET 4.5 on the server?  That would certainly help, as 4.5 contains browser caps for IE11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IE detection doesn't work properly for IE11, which doesn't have the `MSIE` token. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx for the ASP.NET updates that will properly detect IE11 and allow ASP.NET to send JavaScript to the client.

(You probably need to remove your custom IE browser definition file)